# How do I validate data in a form when an anchor tag is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap.  After the user enters data in my form, they click a button to register.  This loads a modal with a summary of the data they entered for them to confirm.  I want to validate the data after they click register, but before the modal loads.  How do I do that?

This is one of my form elements

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input id="inputEmail" class = "span11" type="text" placeholder="Email" name = "inputEmail" maxlength="32">
</div>
```

This loads the modal

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
  <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" id="registerBtn" data-toggle="modal">Register</a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: you can call jqury function onclick event of href

Comment: Might be helpful.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+form+validation+before+submit

Comment: Right, but then how do you prevent the modal from loading if a ValidData() function returns false?  Could you give a short example of the code?  I'm pretty new to this.  Thanks.

Comment: I *think* that if an onclick handler returns false, that will stop jQuery Modal. Try this to be sure. If it still pops up, I am wrong.   <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" id="registerBtn" onclick="return false" data-toggle="modal">Register</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, call function which validate your data. i mentioned how to call function rest you know how to put validation...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rest(){
alert('asdf');
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:rest()" role="button" class="btn" id="registerBtn" data-toggle="modal">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take control of how the Modal appears by doing it in javascript. Remove the data-toggle="modal" attribute and instead hook your button to a function that will eventually do:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

You may have to initialise it beforehand or not, depending on your bootstrap version. That would look like:

```
$('#myModal').modal();
```

For moar infos:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals